# whats is "http-->header--> accept"

Tags: http-accept-header

**Request**

```
Accept:audio/basic
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
....
```

**response**

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:133
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
..........
```

My accept `audio/basic` only

```
Response Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

`audio/basic` is acceptable for the response  but  response content type is `text/html` Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the responding web server chose not to honor the Accept: header. Likely reasons for this include:

- The server doesn't have the ability to serve that resource with an **audio/basic** type, so it fell back to what it had available.
- The response is an error message. Since you don't show us the response code, it's impossible to determine this from your provided information, but it should be available to you.

Comment: The Response is not an error message. It has success response  code 200

Comment: Then the server just isn't able to render that resources as type `audio/basic`.